# Android Progress dialog for Searching Bluetooth devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, progressdialog

I tried to implement an Android app that must search for bluetooth devices(with a condition for device's name). When the search button is pressed, there must be shown a progress dialog while the search is made. First time, without the progress dialog, the app worked but now when I press the button, sometimes it runs ok, it shows the dialog and after that the found devices, but other times, the dialog disappears and no result is shown(or the result is shown long time after it).
Here is my code:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


public class ConnectionScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
    //Declaration of components
    private static final String TAG = "ConnectionScreen";
    public static final String BROADCAST = "PACKAGE_NAME.android.action.broadcast";
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private Button buttonSearch;
    private CheckBox checkBoxAutoConnect;
    private ListView listOfDevices;
    private TextView statusId;
    private TextView statusConnection;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothadapt;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> deviceAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection_screen);

    linkViewToResources();


    listOfDevices.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);


    bluetoothadapt = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothadapt == null) {
        statusConnection.setText("Not supported");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        buttonSearch.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        buttonSearch.setEnabled(true);
    }


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

}

private void linkViewToResources() {
    buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            find(view);

        }
    });
    checkBoxAutoConnect = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAutoconnect);
    listOfDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOfDevices);
    deviceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
}





final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the arrayAdapter
                // get paired devices
                if (device.getName().startsWith("HXM") && device.getName().length() == 9) {
                    deviceAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    //deviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };

    public void find(View view) {
        if (bluetoothadapt.isDiscovering()) {
            // the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
            bluetoothadapt.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        else {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(ConnectionScreen.this);
            this.dialog.setMessage("Searching");
            this.dialog.show();

            deviceAdapter.clear();
            bluetoothadapt.startDiscovery();
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            sendBroadcast(enableBtIntent);
            //new ProgressTask().execute(null, null, null);
            //////////////////////////
        }


    }



 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            if (bReceiver != null) {
                unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }



 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.connection_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }



 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }
```

Does anybody how to solve this?
Thanks.

UPDATE:

And another problem that I've encountered during test is with the search button: when I press it first time, it runs, but when I press it second time, it doesn't run, and so on. When it doesn't run, nothing is shown in the logcat. When it runs, this is what is printed in logcat:

```
 07-14 10:34:58.466  22020-22020/com.yast D/ProgressBar﹕ setProgress = 0
07-14 10:34:58.466  22020-22020/com.yast D/ProgressBar﹕ setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
07-14 10:34:58.466  22020-22020/com.yast D/ProgressBar﹕ mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
07-14 10:34:58.496  22020-22020/com.yast W/ResourceType﹕ Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
07-14 10:34:59.527  22020-22020/com.yast E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-14 10:34:59.527  22020-22020/com.yast E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-14 10:34:59.777  22020-22020/com.yast E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-14 10:34:59.777  22020-22020/com.yast E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Comment: are you sure that your onReceive() in the Receiver get called?

Comment: @Arash: yes, if it wouldn't be called, it would show all the bluetooth devices in the area, but it shows only the ones with the wanted name format (HXMxxxxxx, x - number)

Comment: maybe the problem is you initialize your dialog inside your button click so it may instaniate two instance of the dialog.try initialize your dialog inside oncreate().maybe it helps.

Comment: could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code (when you start discovering and it is searching for devices your code doesn't restart discovering routine, just cancels it):

```
public void find(View view) {
    if (bluetoothadapt.isDiscovering()) {
        // the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
        bluetoothadapt.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(ConnectionScreen.this);
    this.dialog.setMessage("Searching");
    this.dialog.show();

    deviceAdapter.clear();
    bluetoothadapt.startDiscovery();
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    sendBroadcast(enableBtIntent);
    //new ProgressTask().execute(null, null, null);
    //////////////////////////
}
```

**Update** 
From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery%28%29): 
The discovery process usually involves an inquiry scan of about 12 seconds, followed by a page scan of each new device to retrieve its Bluetooth name. 
Device discovery is a heavyweight procedure.

I suppose that you have to wait until discovery routine is finished and there's no ways to speed up this process.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Now it prints for each time I press the button. But I think there is still a flaw in the code, sometimes it takes too much time for showing the found devices, sometimes not. I would like to show them immediately after. Do you know why is this delay?